What is the best way of citing a colleagues not yet given conference presentation?
I am finishing a paper and will probably submit within the next month or so. I would like to cite the upcoming conference presentation of a colleague (wich will also be published as a conference paper in the proceedings). Depending on the lenght of the review process, it is not unlikely that the conference presentation will have been given before my papers' publication (given that it will be accepted, of course), yet the proceedings might take a bit longer to be published.
The colleague already submitted the abstract and is accepted at the conference, so it is quasi certain that the conference paper will be available in the near future.
How do I handle this? From my viewpoint, the options are:

I don't cite the not yet published paper at all
I submit the paper without the citation but if the review drags on long enough I will add the citation once the presentation has been given with a note to the reviewers as to why it was added later in the process
I cite the paper as if it were already published, because by the time my article is published it probably will be as well
I cite the paper as "submitted"


It is common to list such things in the normal way and then add "to appear" at the end. This assumes, of course, that the paper has been accepted and is in process for publication.
Note also, that your initial submission may need an update/revision or two before finalization and you will have a chance to update the listing if the paper has appeared.
